# how to handle Onpress events in react native snap carousel

Tags: javascript, react-native

**I have a class and in that class I am displaying carousel components like this**

***sampleclass.js***

```js
.
.
. 
render{
return (
<Image ..> 
<Text>
text 
</Text>
<Image ..>
<js file tag where carousel is defined />
</Image>

<Text>
text 
</Text>
<Image ..>
<js file tag where carousel is defined />
</Image>
.
.
.
</Image>
);
}

function fname(params..){
I also need to access carousel ref here 
}
```

**and I have another class where I have defined the** *carousel*

***carouselclass.js***

```js
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { Dimensions, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';

import Carousel from 'react-native-snap-carousel';

export default class ExampleCarousel extends PureComponent {
    state = {
        data: [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
    }

    renderItem = () => (
        <View style={styles.tile} />
    );

    render () {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Carousel
                  data={this.state.data}
                  renderItem={this.renderItem}
                  itemWidth={Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.85}
                  sliderWidth={Dimensions.get('window').width}
                  containerCustomStyle={styles.carousel}
                  slideStyle={{ flex: 1 }}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        height: 300
    },
    carousel: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'red'
    },
    tile: {
        flex: 1,
        width: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.85,
        backgroundColor: 'yellow'
    }
});
```

**I have to handle the onPress event of the carousel swipe components  in the function of sampleclass.js**

How can I do this I know how to handle onPress events on react native but couldnt do this with react-native-snap-carousel since I am using it for the first time I have read examples given in the  docs  but couldnt find something related to this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to handle single Carousel item's `onPress` prop, you need to add that to your render item.

**Example**

```
// change this
renderItem = () => (
    <View style={styles.tile} />
);

// to this
_onPressCarousel = () => {
    // here handle carousel press
}
renderItem = () => (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onPressCarousel} style={styles.tile}>
        <Image
            style={styles.button}
            source={require('./myButton.png')}
        />
    </TouchableOpacity>
);
```

Comment: hey thanks that seems to work but 
I also need to check if  the same image is pressed and that is done in the function defined inside **sampleclass.js** 

there are 2 fields where the carousel swipe components appear 
and they both are having the same 8 swipe components and thats y i need to check this 

how can i do this

Answer (score 0):

```
<Carousel
...
  renderItem={(carousel, parallaxProps) =>
    this._renderItem(carousel, parallaxProps)
}
...
/>


_renderItem(carousel, parallaxProps) {
  const { item } = carousel;
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => {
        this._handlePress(item._id);
      }}
    >
    ...
```

Comment: Please add details to your answer about what was causing an issue and how you solved it.